# Right way to define multiple variables,arrays or something else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Sorry if question are little dumb,but I am totally noob with this.

I write code,but I am not sure that I do this on right way. My code work, but it is not seam right to me.

I need to save multiple values,that have something relationship between itself.

For example I add at list mark of tv,size of screen and button to remove this from list.

For this i use 3 arrays arrayName,arraySize and arrayButton.
button have generates names butDel1,butDel2,butDel3,etc...

i push values in arrayName with `arrayName.push` i do same for array size, and i generate buttons name with for loop. than i check is butDel in name,if is i copy number, and remove tv on number position if is butDel3 i  remove name,and size on position3...etc...
and than i again define button array with for that get all button names...

In code it is doing something like this ( whole code is to big i wold write important part):

First define of arrays

```
var arrayName    = [];
var arraySize    = [];
var arrayButton  = [];
```

After that adding value:
    arrayName.push("toshiba");
    arraySize.push("50 cm");
    arrayName.push("samsung");
    arraySize.push("80 cm");
    arrayName.push("sony");
    arraySize.push("55 cm");

Now i need to define button that have number of place in array.

```
if (aarayButton.length < arrayName.length) {
    arrayButton = [];
    for (y = 0; y < arrayName.length; y++) {
        arrayButton.push("btnDel" + y.toString());
    }
}
```

When i want to remove from array:

```
if (event.target.id.indexOf("btnDel") != -1) {
    id = event.target.id.replace('btnDel', '');
    arrayName.splice(id, 1);
    arraySize.splice(id, 1);
```

Now i define again button array(that song wrong to me)
    if (aarayButton.length < arrayName.length) {
        arrayButton = [];
        for (y = 0; y < arrayName.length; y++) {
            arrayButton.push("btnDel" + y.toString());
        }
    }

for example i click on butDel1 i splice
   arrayName.splice(1, 1);

(in this code "samsung")

i generate button array again to have only butDel0 and butDel1,if i not do that i have butdel2 and not arrayname[2].

I am sure that for this better logic, but like I say I am noob and i not have idea about something better than arrays. I was think something about json,but i not find way.

Thank You.

Comment: please add your code

Comment: You should JS objects instead of multiple arrays. And please clarify what does butDel do?

Comment: @Man Programmer, thanx for suggestion, i am new on forum. I add part of code(whole code is very big,but i think that will enough to understand what i do.

Comment: @nisargjhaveri on Man Programmer suggestion, i added code. Thanx

Comment: Where's the `jQuery` part of this question? Please re-tag it property. This is basic `Javascript`.

Comment: @zverko, I am a little confused. What are you doing with the `arrayButton`? Are you appending buttons to DOM with some event handler? From where did the event come?

Comment: @nisargjhaveri btnDel is part of div, i generatee button in div,check click,check if click commponent have btnDel in name,and getting "id". Thanks to the efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arrayName    = [];
var arrayButton  = [];
 arrayName["toshiba"] = "50 cm";
 arrayName["samsung"] = "80 cm";
```

for delete

```
 if (event.target.id.indexOf("btnDel") != -1) {
        id = event.target.id.replace('btnDel', '');
        delete arrayName[id];
     }
```

try this associative method

Comment: You don't have to store buttons in an array.

Comment: @nisargjhaveri sorry i dont understand,how i than get "id" is button1 or button2, and are i need to delete arrayName[1]; 2 or whatever button i click?  Thanx